# 2-bit adder implementation

Tags: adder

How can I implement this 2-bit adder circuit:

[image: Schematic]

*([source](http://img.f-alpha.net/electronics/digital_electronics/adder/circuit_diagram_2_bit_adder.gif))*

Onto http://www.neuroproductions.be/logic-lab/ or logic.ly?
After several attempts (and in spite of the half adder and full adder working) I cannot seem to get this adder working.

Here is the half adder & full adder:

[image: Half Adder & Full Adder]

Comment: We need more information to help. Please show us your half-adder, full-adder, and failed 2-bit adder.

Comment: @gbulmer I have now added the successful half-adder & full adder design. The failed 2-bit adder is trying to recreate the 1st image.

Comment: I apologise, but I don't understand your problem. I think that logic-lab is a poor piece of software, but I believe I got the two-bit adder of the schematic working okay. I couldn't get the online demo of logic.ly to work, and I'm not going to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine in the free online version.  The only goofy thing was that I had to use these 3-to-1 outputs to get it to allow the output of one gate to go to multiple inputs of the next stage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine to me, most likely it's a incorrect software bug. I looked over the design, and that is my same design for a full adder.

**OR:**

You may have accidentally put a *xor* for the or in the 1 output, or a *nand* , or *xnor* for a input, and maybe I didn't notice it. Just look it over, and you'll get a result, likely. You have the correct design.